# 7z segmentation fault when creating archive

Tags: 7zip, py7zlib

I'm using 7zip to compress a large folder into an archive and I'm password protecting it.

I installed 7zip through the mirrors:

```
wget https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/Packages/p/p7zip-16.02-10.el6.x86_64.rpm
wget https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/Packages/p/p7zip-plugins-16.02-10.el6.x86_64.rpm

sudo rpm -U --quiet p7zip-16.02-10.el6.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -U --quiet p7zip-plugins-16.02-10.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

To create the archive, I run `7z a archive.zip output/* -pMyPassword`.

It takes ~30 minutes but finishes scanning the drive outputting:

```
Scanning the drive:
95966 folders, 6573468 files, 1178143530189 bytes (1098 GiB)
```

Then it starts to create the archive before failing with the following error:
`/bin/7z: line 2:  9979 Segmentation fault      "/usr/libexec/p7zip/7z" "$@"`.

It *seems* to be related to the binary itself but I cannot find this error mentioned on the 7zip forums or here on Stackoverflow, so I figured I'd write this up to see if anyone has any ideas.

This is the version info:

```
7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,2 CPUs Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz (306F2),ASM,AES-NI)
```